# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code: bin/xcode_backend.sh: No such file or directory

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I'm making an app on flutter, but for some reason when i try to build my app and run it on my device i'm getting this error below.

```
/bin/sh: /Users/maps/Desktop/flutter/bin/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh: No such file or directory
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

**I tried to:**

- Update sdk path because i transfer the project from a windows PC to my macbook
- Cleaning and re-building the project
- Deleting `Pods` folder and `podfile.lock` file and running `pod install` again

But none of these solutions worked for me.

**Note:** I'm beginner on Flutter development :-)